# Busybox: check whether the PSU cable is connected or not

Tags: busybox, psutil

Is there any command or some way to check from busybox if the network cable is connected or disconnected.

So far I have tried python's psutil package but it seems that psutil is not installed on the busybox system:

```
import psutil

psutil.sensors_battery().power_plugged
```

Busybox version:

```
busybox | head -1
    
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
```